# How to Run Seeder to Multiple Related Table at Once on Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating 3 table which related each other like these:

```
Template hasOne Attribute


Template hasOne Link
```

I want to fill Attribute and Link table through Template Seeder.
I have try inserting two function inside Template factory to run it at once, but the second function is not working, only first function work fine.

I want it run all at once.

Here is my code on factory:

```
factory(App\Models\Template\Eloquent\TemplateModel::class, 10)->create()->each(
    function ($template) {
        $template->links()->save(
            factory(App\Models\Template\Eloquent\TemplatelinkModel::class)->make()
        );
    },
    function ($template) {
        $template->attributes()->save(
            factory(App\Models\Template\Eloquent\TemplateattributeModel::class)->make()
        );
    }
);
```

How to do that?
Please some body help me? Thank you.

Comment: Can you show table structure with foreign key for these tables/models?

Comment: The relation is normal, it works now, thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only use one callback function as parameter to the Illuminate\Support\Collection->each() function. In your case, using both save operations inside the same function sent as callback to each() would do the trick.

```
factory(App\Models\Template\Eloquent\TemplateModel::class, 10)->create()->each(
    function ($template) {
        $template->links()->save(
            factory(App\Models\Template\Eloquent\TemplatelinkModel::class)->make()
        );
        $template->attributes()->save(
            factory(App\Models\Template\Eloquent\TemplateattributeModel::class)->make()
        );
    }
);
```

For more information on how to use each() and other Collection functions, refer to https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections .

Comment: Cool! It works! Thank you so much. You save my time :)